# Recursion schemes using `Fix` on a data-type that's already a Functor?

Tags: haskell, functor, recursive-datastructures, recursion-schemes, fixpoint-combinators

Still working on my text editor [Rasa](https://github.com/chrispenner/rasa).

At the moment I'm building out the system for tracking viewports/splits (similar to vim splits). It seemed natural to me to represent this structure as a tree:

```
data Dir = Hor
         | Vert
         deriving (Show)

data Window a =
  Split Dir SplitInfo (Window a) (Window a)
    | Single ViewInfo a
    deriving (Show, Functor, Traversable, Foldable)
```

This works great, I store my `View`s in the tree, and then I can traverse/fmap over them to alter them, it also dovetails with the lens package pretty well!

I've been learning about [Recursion Schemes](https://medium.com/@jaredtobin/practical-recursion-schemes-c10648ec1c29#.nlgrc4ibh) lately and it seems like this is a suitable use-case for them since the tree is a recursive data-structure.

I managed to figure it out well enough to build out the Fixpoint version:

```
data WindowF a r =
  Split Dir SplitInfo r r
    | Single ViewInfo a
    deriving (Show, Functor)

type Window a = Fix (WindowF a)
```

However, now the Functor instance is used up by the `r`;

I've tried a few variations of

```
deriving instance Functor Window
```

But it chokes because window is a type synonym.

And:

```
newtype Window a = Window (Fix (WindowF a)) deriving Functor
```

And that fails too;

```
• Couldn't match kind ‘* -> *’ with ‘*’
    arising from the first field of ‘Window’ (type ‘Fix (WindowF a)’)
• When deriving the instance for (Functor Window)
```

1. Is it still possible to define fmap/traverse over `a`? Or do I need to do these operations using [recursion-schemes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes) primitives? Do I implement Bifunctor? What would the instance implementation look like?

Rest of the types are [here](https://github.com/ChrisPenner/rasa/blob/render-pref-recursion-schemes/rasa-ext-views/src/Rasa/Ext/Views.hs#L29), the project doesn't compile because I don't have the proper Functor instance for Window...

Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, this *is* two questions in one. Please don't do that.

Comment: Not sure what I was thinking haha, since you answered the first I'll pull the second into a new one. Thanks BTW!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a lot of wrestling I've come to the conclusion that a better choice is to define two data-types; a standard datatype that has the properties you want (in this case Bifunctor) and a Recursive Functor data-type for which you can define `Base`, `Recursive` and `Corecursive` instances for.

Here's what it looks like:

```
{-# language DeriveFunctor, DeriveTraversable, TypeFamilies  #-}

import Data.Typeable
import Data.Bifunctor
import Data.Functor.Foldable

data BiTree b l =
  Branch b (BiTree b l) (BiTree b l)
    | Leaf l
    deriving (Show, Typeable, Functor, Traversable, Foldable)

instance Bifunctor BiTree where
  bimap _ g (Leaf x) = Leaf (g x)
  bimap f g (Branch b l r) = Branch (f b) (bimap f g l) (bimap f g r)

data BiTreeF b l r =
  BranchF b r r
    | LeafF l
    deriving (Show, Functor, Typeable)

type instance Base (BiTree a b) = BiTreeF a b
instance Recursive (BiTree a b) where
  project (Leaf x) = LeafF x
  project (Branch s l r) = BranchF s l r

instance Corecursive (BiTree a b) where
  embed (BranchF sp x xs) = Branch sp x xs
  embed (LeafF x) = Leaf x
```

You can now use your base type (BiTree) throughout your code like normal; and when you decide to use a recursion scheme you simply need to remember that when unpacking you use the 'F' versions of the constructors:

```
anyActiveWindows :: Window -> Bool
anyActiveWindows = cata alg
  where alg (LeafF vw) = vw^.active
        alg (BranchF _ l r) = l || r
```

Note that if you end up rebuilding a set of windows you'll still use the NON-F versions on the right-hand side of the `=`.

I've defined the following for my scenario and it works great; I've got both `Functor` and `Bifunctor` for `Window` as I wanted without even using a newtype:

```
type Window = BiTree Split View

data SplitRule =
  Percentage Double
  | FromStart Int
  | FromEnd Int
  deriving (Show)

data Dir = Hor
        | Vert
        deriving (Show)

data Split = Split
  { _dir :: Dir
  , _splitRule :: SplitRule
  } deriving (Show)

makeLenses ''Split

data View = View
  { _active :: Bool
  , _bufIndex :: Int
  } deriving (Show)

makeLenses ''View
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you want to use the version of `Fix` from `Data.Bifunctor.Fix`:

```
newtype Fix p a = In { out :: p (Fix p a) a }

instance Bifunctor p => Functor (Fix p) where
  fmap f (In x) = In (bimap (fmap f) f x)
```

You'll have to change your `WindowF` type to match:

```
data WindowF r a =
  Split Dir SplitInfo r r
    | Single ViewInfo a
    deriving (Show, Functor)

instance Bifunctor WindowF where
  bimap f _g (Split dir si x y) = Split dir si (f x) (f y)
  bimap _f g (Single vi a) = Single vi (g a)

newtype Window a = Window (Fix WindowF a) deriving Functor
```

It's possible to use `recursion-schemes` with this, along with an auxiliary type:

```
import Data.Functor.Foldable hiding (Fix (..))
import Data.Profunctor.Unsafe
import Data.Coerce

newtype Flip p a b = Flip {unFlip :: p b a}

instance Bifunctor p => Bifunctor (Flip p) where
  bimap f g (Flip x) = Flip (bimap g f x)

instance Bifunctor p => Functor (Flip p a) where
  fmap = coerce (first :: (x -> y) -> p x a -> p y a)
    :: forall x y . (x -> y) -> Flip p a x -> Flip p a y

type instance Base (Fix p a) = Flip p a
instance Bifunctor p => Recursive (Fix p a) where
  project = Flip #. out
  cata f = f . Flip . first (cata f) . out
```

Unfortunately, defining `Recursive` for the newtype-wrapped version is a little trickier:

```
newtype Window a = Window {getWindow :: Fix WindowF a} deriving (Functor)
type instance Base (Window a) = Flip WindowF a

instance Recursive (Window a) where
  project = coerce #. project .# getWindow
  cata = (. getWindow) #. cata
```

Comment: Do we need the newtype? What does it provide in this case? Is it necessary for the Functor instance?

I'm having a bit of trouble using this now, for instance the following (trivial) example works with the regular Fix, but not with the new Bifunctor Fix, take a look at `allTree` here: https://gist.github.com/ChrisPenner/aa6083478d2d1100f62a974860aae529

Sorry for all the trouble, I'm pretty new to all this Fix stuff, and now having two different versions of it isn't making it any easier haha.

Comment: @ChrisPenner, does that help?

Comment: This is considerably more complicated than I'd thought it would be; I think I may go back to my simple Functor solution unless you have any simpler ideas. I'd like to learn recursion-schemes, but if something as simple as having a Functor datatype is this complicated then I don't know that I'm up to the task. I really do appreciate the explanations though! For some reason stack is refusing to install the 'profunctors' lib, so I'm even having trouble even trying this out. Despite that, even if I could figure it out, I think it would be difficult for other programmers to understand the result :(

Comment: @ChrisPenner, you can certainly use the `recursion-schemes` approach and write the `Functor` instance by hand. I suspect the prettiest way may involve writing a bifunctorish clone of `recursion-schemes`, but that surely seems like overkill.

Comment: Hrmm, interesting; I just rediscovered the [Plated](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Plated.html) section of the lens library; it has para, and you can use `transformOf` as `cata`, It's perhaps a little different but has similar power without needing to mangle your underlying data-structure which is nice. So far it's worked for my needs.

Comment: Ran into a few problems with that plated too because functions like `transform` have the signature `(a -> a) -> a -> a` which doesn't allow changing the type as part of a folding operations like `cata` does... *sigh*. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: Ended up going a different direction again; see my answer; It's simpler for me to understand than `Data.Bifunctor.Fix`; let me know what you think of it.